# Xamarin custom model in custom view(BindableProperty)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

well, i'm trying to make a custom view which is like user thumbnail view.
the view(ViewCell?) displays UserModel(my custom model)'s thumbnail + username.

this is the code in `UploaderCell.xaml.cs`

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty UploaderProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "Uploader", 
            returnType: typeof(UserModel), 
            declaringType: typeof(UploaderCell)
        ); 

    public UserModel Uploader
    {
        get
        { return GetValue(UploaderProperty) as UserModel; }
        set 
        { SetValue(UploaderProperty, value); }
    }
```

and this is used like `<UploaderCell Uploader="{Binding post.uploader}"/>`

in some where else.

and the error i get is `System.InvalidCastException Class`
it's not my mistake about actually passing the wrong data.

so my question is, is it impossible to make BindableProperties with non basic types(string, int ,ect..)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use complex types and is something I do all the time. What you have posted of your code looks correct.

I would check the code in your view model to see what you are actually binding to that value as that might be the cause of your error. If you are binding the wrong type then that might lead to the error.

Comment: is there any possible ways to debug binding?? + i'm not using MVVM just xaml and xaml.cs some like this.(or my miss understanding) would that be a problem?

Comment: or.. could you get me any example projects containing those concepts?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your data model has

```
{ get; set; }
```

this..

ah..

Comment: That would do it - if your view model (I know you say you are not using MVVM, but really you are - the thing you are binding is to all intents and purposes a view model) doesn't use public properties for values, you can't bind to them